What is the subject and meaning of these scrolls from a former client?
These are photos of two framed scrolls given to me several years ago by a client in gratitude for my services.


The left side picture: 福如東海長流水 and 100 different styles of 福(good fortune) as background
The right side picture: 壽比南山不老松 and 100 different styles of 壽(Longevity) as background
「福如東海， 壽比南山」is a blessing phrase for older generation people's birthday (younger people would say it to their seniors on their birthdays, but never the other way around)

福如東海(good fortune as vast as The East Sea)

壽比南山(Longevity compares to The South Mountains)


「福如東海長流水」 and 「壽比南山不老松」 is a couplet

長流水(long flowing water)

不老松(unaging pine)


This writing in simplified Chinese:「福如东海长流水,寿比南山不老松」
~~
甲申年 (the last 甲申年 was 2004. The one before it was 1944)
夏(summer)於(at)
西雅图 (Seattle)
胡家誠 (Hu Jiacheng - the author)
書 (wrote)

The background characters are the various styles of 福 and 壽 respectively.

you can call it 百福百壽聯

Yes, it is a good call.
